# Erro de requisição ajax para carregar no google map

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo uma requisição código ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"url.php",
    data:{
        ida : href,  
    },
    beforeSend: function(){

    },
    success:function(data){          
      $("#mapa").html(data);                 
    }
});
```

Requisição está sendo feita com sucesso, sem problema. 
O que ocorre é ao carregar o resultado, no caso é um mapa do google maps, da um erro: You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

sendo que meu arquivo url.php é :

```
<div id="gmap_canvas"></div>
<div id='map-label'></div>
    <!-- JavaScript to show google map -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init_map() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>)
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<?php echo $formatted_address; ?>"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
```

Não tenho em nenhuma outra parte do código referencia para inclusão do scritp do mapa, é carregado diretamente pelo arquivo url.php via ajax.

Acessando direto no navegador a url.php funciona perfeitamente, se for via ajax não funciona, da o erro relatado.

Gostaria de saber o porque do erro, pois estou fazendo referencia do script do mapas apenas uma vez e não múltiplas vezes conforme o erro informado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma com ssl, se você colocar o sensor como false, não precisa usar a KEY:

```
<script src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=pt-br" async defer></script>
```

E não esqueça de executar o método: `init_map()`, você pode fazer isso diretamente da URL do script, colocando mais um parâmetro:
`&callback=init_map` ou fazendo um auload:

```
(function(){
     init_map();
})();
```

OBS: Dá uma olhada neste script do [**Banco24Horas**](http://banco24horas.com.br/js/busca.terminal.js)

Se não funcionar, crie uma [**API Key**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key).

[**Aqui tem mais informações**](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/google-apis/google-maps-api-v3-criando-um-mapa-personalizado.html) para sua orientação.

Aqui um exemplo funcionando:

```
  <?php $latitude = '-23.642952'; $longitude='-46.786652'; $formatted_address='teste';?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: <?php echo $latitude;?>, lng: <?php echo $longitude;?>},
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            zoom: 8,
            center: {lat: <?php echo $latitude;?>, lng: <?php echo $longitude;?>}
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<?php echo $formatted_address; ?>"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: funcionou aparece o mapa, mas se for no console js o erro continua e deu outro erro: Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa incluir isso:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SUA_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

... no lugar do que você colocou sem definir uma KEY gerada pelo Google.

Comment: precisa da key? ou apenas o destaque em vermelho?

Comment: É padrão do Google o que está em vermelho.

Comment: como relatei, sem requisição ajax para mostrar o mapa funciona. com requisição ajax para mostrar o mapa não está funcionando.

Comment: A key, não é obrigatória, é só colocar o sensor como false.

Comment: mesmo assim não funciona. o erro citado permanece